# Compare JSON values and get new JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have following **JSON**

```
 [
  {
    "Key": "file/ERROR-FILE1-123.xlsx",
  },
   {
    "Key": "file/PROCESS-FILE1-123.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/PROCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/SUCCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/PROCESS-FILE3-121.xlsx",
  },
]
```

What I want to achieve here first check the last part of the JSON key string if it is the same then I will check PROCESS and ERROR and will display the ERROR file...

for example in my JSON `key[0]` is "file/ERROR-FILE1-123.xlsx" and `key[1]` is "file/PROCESS-FILE1-123.xlsx" so for both the `keys` -FILE1-123.xlsx is same so will filter error file and add it in new JSON. same with other JSON if last part is same then will give priority to SUCCESS and ERROR and add only these file to new JSON but if PROCESS key is single I mean no ERROR or SUCCESS is available then will display only Process file

So my expected new JSON should be like this. Kindly help how to achieve this as I'm completely new to UI technology still in a learning phase. If is there any better way to achieve this please share

```
 [
  {
    "Key": "file/ERROR-FILE1-123.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/SUCCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/PROCESS-FILE3-121.xlsx",
  },
 ]
```

Comment: Will the format of the files always be `file/[TYPE]-FILE[NUMBER]-[NUMBER].xlsx`?

Comment: yes it will always be the same

Comment: yes format will  always be file/[TYPE]-FILE[NUMBER]-[NUMBER].xlsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could separate the state from the strings, group by filename and get a priorized non process object.

```js
function getParts(s) {
    return (s.match(/^(.*)(ERROR|PROCESS|SUCCESS)-(.*)$/) || []).slice(1);
}

var data = [{ Key: "errorbyte.xlsx" }, { Key: "file/ERROR-FILE1-123.xlsx" }, { Key: "file/PROCESS-FILE1-123.xlsx" }, { Key: "file/PROCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx" }, { Key: "file/SUCCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx" }, { Key: "file/PROCESS-FILE3-121.xlsx" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
            var [left, state, right] = getParts(o.Key),
                file = left + right;

            if (left === undefined) return r;
            if (!r[file] || r[file].state === 'PROCESS') r[file] = { o, state };
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(({ o }) => o);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: please add the string, where you get the error. it looks like, the pattern does not match.

Comment: now i'm working on dynamic file so getting this kind of json data  [{ERROR-FILE1-2020.xlsx},{PROCESS-FILE1-2020.xlsx},{errorbyte.xlsx},{SUCCESS-FILE2-2020.xlsx},{PROCESS-FILE2-2020.xlsx},{PROCESS-FILE3-2020.xlsx}]

Comment: what does this `'errorbyte.xlsx'` means? is it an ERROR type?

Comment: this file should be ignored no need to add this it in new json

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```js
var jsonObj = [{"Key":"ERROR-FILE1-2020.xlsx"},{"Key":'PROCESS-FILE1-2020.xlsx'},{"Key":"errorbyte.xlsx"},{"Key":"SUCCESS-FILE2-2020.xlsx"},{"Key":"PROCESS-FILE2-2020.xlsx"},{"Key":"PROCESS-FILE3-2020.xlsx"}]
var obj = {};
jsonObj.forEach((elem) => {
    let file_name = elem.Key.substring(elem.Key.indexOf("-") + 1)
    let status = elem.Key.substring((elem.Key.indexOf("/") + 1), elem.Key.indexOf("-"))
    if(status!== ''){
    if (obj[file_name] === undefined) {
        
        obj[file_name] = status;
    }
    else {
        if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
            obj[file_name] = status;
            
        }
        if (status === 'ERROR') {
            if(obj[file_name] !== 'SUCCESS'){
            obj[file_name] = status;
        }
        }
    }}
    })
var result = [];
for(key in obj){ let x = {}
    x['Key'] ='file/'+obj[key]+'-'+key 
    result.push(x)
}
console.log(result)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: now i'm working on dynamic file so getting this kind of json data [{ERROR-FILE1-2020.xlsx},{PROCESS-FILE1-2020.xlsx},{errorbyte.xlsx},{SUCCESS-FILE2-2020.xlsx},{PROCESS-FILE2-2020.xlsx},{PROCESS-FILE3-2020.xlsx}]

Comment: this file should be ignored no need to add this in new json

Answer (score 1):

We are going to loop on the array and build a new one, keeping the code and the type of every Key.

At every value, we are going to check what we have on the array we are building, and either replace the value or push a new one.

At the very end of the `Array.reduce` we will have an object containing the code, the Key and the type. We mutate it using a `Array.map` to obtain the desired output.

```js
// Assign a numeric value to every type of file you can get
// The purpose will be to be able to compare types altogether and
// choose which one to keep in case of conflict
function getTypeValue(type) {
  return ({
    PROCESS: 1,
    SUCCESS: 2,
    ERROR: 3,
  })[type];
}

const arr = [{
    Key: 'file/ERROR-FILE1-123.xlsx',
  },
  {
    Key: 'file/PROCESS-FILE1-123.xlsx',
  },
  {
    Key: 'file/PROCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx',
  },
  {
    Key: 'file/SUCCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx',
  },
  {
    Key: 'file/PROCESS-FILE3-121.xlsx',
  },
];

const ret = Object.values(arr.reduce((tmp, {
  Key
}) => {
  // use a regex to extract the interesting values 
  const [,
    type,
    code,
  ] = /(ERROR|PROCESS|SUCCESS)-FILE[0-9]{1}-([0-9]*).xlsx/.exec(Key);

  const typeValue = getTypeValue(type);

  if (tmp[code]) {
    // Check if the new entry should replace the one already stored
    if (tmp[code].typeValue < typeValue) {
      tmp[code] = {
        Key,
        typeValue,
      };
    }
  } else {
    tmp[code] = {
      Key,
      typeValue,
    };
  }

  return tmp;
}, {})).map(({
  Key,
}) => ({
  Key,
}));

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Sample Files Array
var files = [
  {
    "Key": "file/ERROR-FILE1-123.xlsx",
  },
   {
    "Key": "file/PROCESS-FILE1-123.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/PROCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/SUCCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/PROCESS-FILE3-121.xlsx",
  },
]

// This will contain final processed output
var final_list = []

// Creating priority for every status
var priority = {
    "SUCCESS":1,
    "ERROR":2,
    "PROCESS":3
}

// Temporary object for storing status on the basis of filenames
var temp = {}

// Logic
for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
 let file = files[i];
// splitting filename "file/PROCESS-FILE1-123.xlsx" 
    let re = file.Key.split('/')[1].split('-');
    status = re[0]; // "PROCESS"
    filename = re[1]+"-"+re[2]; // "FILE1-123.xlsx"
    if(!(filename in temp)){
        temp[filename] = status;
    }else{
        if(priority[status] < priority[temp[filename]]){
        temp[filename] = status
        }
    }
}

// Making of final object
for(key in temp){
    final_list.push({"Key":"files/"+temp[key]+"-"+key})
}

console.log(final_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

[please check the stackbliz and the console of the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mn6yl7)

```
KeywordString = [
    {
      Key: "file/ERROR-FILE1-123.xlsx"
    },
    {
      Key: "file/PROCESS-FILE1-123.xlsx"
    },
    {
      Key: "file/PROCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx"
    },
    {
      Key: "file/SUCCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx"
    },
    {
      Key: "file/PROCESS-FILE3-121.xlsx"
    }
  ];
  newJSON = [];
  constructor() {
    let map = new Object();

    for (var index = 0; index < this.KeywordString.length; index++) {

      if (
        map[
          this.KeywordString[index].Key.substr(
            this.KeywordString[index].Key.length - 15
          )
        ]
      ) {

      } else {
        map[
          this.KeywordString[index].Key.substr(
            this.KeywordString[index].Key.length - 15
          )
        ] = true;

        this.newJSON.push(this.KeywordString[index]);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.newJSON);
  }
}
```

I made it as an array of object

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://runkit.com/embed/jmcxcv47el2f

[image]

```
let arr = [
  {
    "Key": "file/ERROR-FILE1-123.xlsx",
  },
   {
    "Key": "file/PROCESS-FILE1-123.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/PROCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/SUCCESS-FILE2-111.xlsx",
  },
  {
    "Key": "file/PROCESS-FILE3-121.xlsx",
  },
];

const filterBy = (keep, remove1, remove2) => {
    let values = arr.map(item => item.Key);
    let keeps = values.filter(item => item.includes(keep));
    let names = keeps.map(item => item.replace(`file/${keep}-FILE`,""));    
    names.forEach(name => {       
       arr = arr.filter(item => item.Key !==`file/${remove1}-FILE${name}`);
       if(remove2)
          arr = arr.filter(item => item.Key !==`file/${remove2}-FILE${name}`);
    });    
}

filterBy("ERROR", "SUCCESS", "PROCESS");
filterBy("SUCCESS", "PROCESS");
//arr <<-- This is output;
```

Comment: now i'm working on dynamic file so getting this kind of json data [{ERROR-FILE1-2020.xlsx},{PROCESS-FILE1-2020.xlsx},{errorbyte.xlsx},{SUCCESS-FILE2-2020.xlsx},{PROCESS-FILE2-2020.xlsx},{PROCESS-FILE3-2020.xlsx}]

Comment: it doesn't matter, just adapt this solution.